# How to update an item after being newly created in AWS DynamoDB and Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, next.js, aws-amplify, swr

I am trying to update a query in AWS Dynamo using AWS Amplify on top of Next.js.

My scenario is simple.

On page load, if there exists a user and the user has not visited a page before, a new object will be created with set values using SWR.

```js
const fetchUserSite = async (owner, code) => {
  try {
    // Create site object if no site exists
    if (userData == null) {
      const siteInfo = {
        id: uuidv4(),
        code: parkCode,
        owner: user?.username,
        bookmarked: false,
        visited: false,
      }

      await API.graphql({
        query: createSite,
        variables: {input: siteInfo},
        authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
      })

      console.log(`${code} added for the first time`)
    }
    return userData || null
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Site not added by user', data, err)
  }
}


 // Only call the fetchUserSite method if `user` exists
  const {data} = useSWR(user ? [user?.username, parkCode] : null, fetchUserSite)
```

Currently, this works. The object is added to the database with the above attributes. HOWEVER, when I click a button to update this newly created object, I get an error of  `path: null, locations: (1) […], message: "Variable 'input' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'ID!'"`

This is my call to update the object when I click a button with the onClick handler "handleDBQuery".

```js
const handleDBQuery = async () => {
  await API.graphql({
    query: updateSite,
    variables: {
      input: {
        id: data?.id,
        bookmarked: true,
        owner: user?.username,
      },
    },
    authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
  })
  console.log(`${name} Bookmarked`)
}
```

My hunch is that the updateSite query does not know about the createSite query on page load.

In short, how can I update an item after I just created it?

Comment: Maybe the `data?.id` happens to be undefined here? Cloud you console.log(data?.id) above the line `await API.graphql({` of the updateSite.

Comment: I get undefined for `data?.id`. Is there a better way to implement this feature to begin with?

Comment: @asinkxcoswt I am getting some unexplained behavior. When I seemingly click to another window or switch tabs and click the button again to update the Site, the data is updated. Why is this the case?

Comment: In that case, I believe the problem is not in graphql or Amplify itself, but may relate to how you manage the state in React. To answer this, I will need a more detailed version of the source code. Maybe, could you upload it to Github and send me a link?

Comment: Hi @asinkxcoswt, here is my GitHub repo: https://github.com/tyler-morales/visit-national-parks/blob/bug/fix-unique-park-ids/pages/park/%5BparkCode%5D.js

Comment: Hi @asinkxcoswt, here is direct link to the file: https://github.com/tyler-morales/visit-national-parks/blob/bug/fix-unique-park-ids/pages/park/%5BparkCode%5D.js


Here is the link to look at the repo: https://github.com/tyler-morales/visit-national-parks/pull/15

Comment: I could not access the link https://github.com/tyler-morales/visit-national-parks/blob/bug/fix-unique-park-ids/pages/park/%5BparkCode%5D.js, it shows 404 page not found for me. Maybe I don't have the permission to access.

Comment: However, I looked into the code at master branch (not sure if it the same version of yours), and follow along as you describe. I found that the `data?.id` here comes from a state variable and it is set only before the call to `createSite`. I suggest you try `setId` again using the data returned from the `createSite`.

Comment: And if it is the case, it can answer your discovered unexplained behavior. When you switch tabs, it is possible that the data is reload.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the code at master branch and follow along as you describe. I found that the `data?.id` here comes from a state variable and it is set only before the call to `createSite`. I suggest you try setId again using the data returned from the `createSite`

Try this

```
const fetchUserSite = async (owner, code) => {
  try {
    // Create site object if no site exists
    if (userData == null) {
      const siteInfo = {
        id: uuidv4(),
        code: parkCode,
        owner: user?.username,
        bookmarked: false,
        visited: false,
      }

      const { data: newData } = await API.graphql({
        query: createSite,
        variables: {input: siteInfo},
        authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
      });

      setId(newData.id); // <====== here (or setId(siteInfo.id))

      console.log(`${code} added for the first time`)
      return newData; // <======= and this, maybe? (you may have to modify the qraphql query to make it return the same item as in the listSite
    }
    return userData || null
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Site not added by user', data, err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. This worked out perfectly. What was happening, at least what I think was happening, was that when I tried to call `data?.id` from the `updateSite` query, it wasn't defined globally yet, so it had no access to the id.